# Appcelerator issue: currentWindow : Titanium.UI.Window - REMOVED from Titanium since SDK 6.0.0

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

According to the [documentation](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI-property-currentWindow), `currentWindow` has been removed along with the `Titanium.UI.Window.url` property to load JavaScript files in their own contexts. I have successfully removed the URL references using `require()` instead.

I have inherited a project that refers to `currentWindow` for managing different page assets, like so:

```
var thisWindow = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
// var thisWindow = Ti.UI.currentWindow; - also doesn't work
var nav = Titanium.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
    window: thisWindow
});

thisWindow.nav = nav;
nav.open();

var detailWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    backButtonTitle: '',
    navTintColor: '#FFF',
    barColor: '#222222',
    getURL: 'http://google.com',
    titleControl: Ti.UI.createLabel({
         //text: 'TITLE',
         color: '#FFF',
         font: {
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: 'bold'
         }
     })
  });

  detailWindow = require('details');
  // add the detail to the nav window
  detailWindow.nav = thisWindow.nav;
```

Here are the contents of details.js:

```
var window = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
var website = window.getURL;

var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    backgroundColor:"#fff",
    url:website
});

window.add(webview);
```

And as this is no longer supported I'm getting the error:

`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'thisWindow.nav=nav')`

How do I bring this method up to date (ideally without a huge rewrite, as there are many pages and page-elements linked in this way).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the commonjs structure.

If you need to pass a window from one file to the other, provide it using setters.

```
// main.js
var details = require('details');
details.setWindow(myWindowVar);

// details.js
var window;
exports.setWindow = function(win){
    window = win;
}
```

The other way around using get aso works of course.

```
// details.js
exports.window = window;

// main.js
detailWindow = require('details').window;
```

Keep in mind though, when using `require` it is loaded in memory. When requireing again later, you're hitting the same thing, it won't re-generate. In case you do want that you need to make functions that create it, and run that.

```
//details.js
function createWindow(){
  var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
  return win;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'll take a look at this today. What is `myWindowVar`for?

Comment: just a placeholder where you store a reference in to the relevant window

Comment: How do you then reference this ```myWindowVar```, ie sending a variable from ```main.js``` to ```details.js```? Thanks

Comment: it is just a window you created yourself... so `var myWindowVar = Ti.UI.createWindow()` basically. It is just an example